# Firefox addon. Communicating using child_process with native app

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Following this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process), I created an add-on that launches a native  child process. The child process can send data to the extension using StdOut of the process, no issues there. However when I try to send data from Extension (add-on script ) to the native app  using the  emit(target,'data', 'the data') ; emit(target,'end'); as mentioned  in the MDN documentation, it seems  like  the app recieves the message only once.  If I try to again  do   emit(target,'data',..) ; emit(target,'end') , again .. it is not sent to the native app. I debugged it and looks like after  we emit('end') , it removes some listeners and next time when emit() is called there is no registered listeners and it does not actually dispatch the event. Would really appreciate if some one could point me to what I am missing.

Comment: then just don't emit the `end`?

Comment: thanks,  if I don't emit 'end'  then the  'data'  is not actually flushed and my native app does not get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emitting `end` likely closes the output stream or something to that effect, so simply don't emit `end` until you're actually done sending data for good.

Comment: Thanks , end was the issue . and some problem was in my native app . .it was expecting a new line so now while emitting I emit 'data'+"\n" and now the application can get all the data everytime.